# Connect to Cassandra DB within Play framework by using Kundera

Tags: cassandra, playframework-2.0, kundera

I tried using [Kundera](https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/wiki/Getting-Started-in-5-minutes) method but I have no idea where to put the persistence.xml, i tried putting it in conf/WEB-INF/ but when I tried running it said that **"Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named cassandra_pu"**.

Can somebody show mw where i were wrong? Is there any other way to connect Cassandra to Play 2.0.4?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

For Kundera the persistence.xml should typically be in $PROJECT_ROOT/src/META-INF/persistence.xml

Comment: As per this issue, it is not able to found any persistence provider, which means either your persistence.xml is missing it or you may defined it incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is PlayOrm for cassandra is nearly done with it's playframework plugin.  Still need to do a playframework module AND it has the in-memory version as well for rapid development.  It should be done by the end of next week.

Documentation on playorm with playframework can be found here

https://github.com/deanhiller/playorm/wiki/PlayFramework-1.2.x-Support

Comment: Any urge to update this to the new Play Framework 2.3.x? Thx :)

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look on:
https://github.com/downloads/impetus-opensource/Kundera-Examples/project%20(1).zip
for reference.

And

https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/wiki/Getting-Started-in-5-minutes

should help you on how to use it.

-Vivek

Answer (score 0):

It should be put under conf/META-INF folder.
Below link should help you getting kundera work with Play!

http://techrecipes.in/2013/07/06/play-nosql-building-nosql-applications-with-play-framework/